# k8s operator list nodes has permission issue?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

I'm trying to use my operator to check if a pod is sitting on a tainted node.

To get the node's taint information, I used

```
err := r.Get(ctx, client.ObjectKey{Name: pod.Spec.NodeName}, node)
```

which works fine with the fakeclient in k8s.

However, when I run it against an EKS cluster, I got the following error:

```
"msg":"pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.24.10/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: failed to list *v1.Node: nodes is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:mike-6mdj7thh:mike-kubernetes-operator-controller-manager\" cannot list resource \"nodes\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope
```

How should I fix it? OR
How should I debug this type of issue?

Comment: You would need to create the necessary RBAC resources (probably a ClusterRole and a ClusterRoleBinding) to grant your service account the ability to list nodes. See e.g. [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

Comment: great! Thanks for the pointer! I have kept using Role and RoleBinding. That's why it failed.

Comment: ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding to access Nodes.

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: mike-clusterrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
  - create
  - update
  - patch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: mike-clusterrolebinding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: mike-clusterrole
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: mike-kubernetes-operator-controller-manager
  namespace: {{ .Namespace }}
```